# Android application developed with Qt 5 and incorporating the AWS C ++ library crashes

Tags: android, c++, qt, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to develop an **Android Application**. This software use the AWS services. The compilation and link work but **it crashes at the very beginning of the execution.**

- I'm using **Qt 5.11** and I think that the configuration is good (I'm using the **last Android SDK and the NDK 10e**) because I can run a simple Android application
- I'm using the last **AWS C++ library**. I compiled this library using this cake command : `cmake  -DBUILD_ONLY="email;cognito-identity;lambda;core;cognito-idp;identity-management" -DNDK_DIR="/Downloads/android-ndk-r10e" -DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared -DTARGET_ARCH=ANDROID -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/aws-sdk-cpp/aws_build_android/build_dynamic_output" /aws-sdk-cpp/aws_build_android/aws-sdk-cpp-master`

A s I said, the application crashes with this ultimate debug message:
 **F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8731 (qtMainLoopThrea)**

Here you are the complete list of application debug messages :

```
E Zygote  : isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
E libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
E libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
W SELinux : SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G930F_8.0.0_0018, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
I SELinux : SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android
I zygote  : Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
D ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
I zygote  : no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=31KB, data=27KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=31KB, data=27KB
I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
I QtCore  : Start
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android-YwAVQhCj0m2GFmkjJTkxTg==/lib/arm/libQt5Network.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android-YwAVQhCj0m2GFmkjJTkxTg==/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android-YwAVQhCj0m2GFmkjJTkxTg==/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android-YwAVQhCj0m2GFmkjJTkxTg==/lib/arm/libQt5Quick.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android-YwAVQhCj0m2GFmkjJTkxTg==/lib/arm/libQt5Widgets.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android-YwAVQhCj0m2GFmkjJTkxTg==/lib/arm/libQt5Charts.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android-YwAVQhCj0m2GFmkjJTkxTg==/lib/arm/libQt5QuickParticles.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android-YwAVQhCj0m2GFmkjJTkxTg==/lib/arm/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android-YwAVQhCj0m2GFmkjJTkxTg==/lib/arm/libQt5QuickControls2.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
I Qt      : qt started
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :        674 us, width=30, height=30
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :       1560 us, width=66, height=96
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :       1363 us, width=66, height=96
I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=59KB, data=54KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=54KB
I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :        413 us, width=5, height=5
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :        527 us, width=30, height=30
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :        593 us, width=30, height=30
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :        412 us, width=5, height=5
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :        461 us, width=12, height=48
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :        457 us, width=12, height=48
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :       1234 us, width=66, height=48
D skia    : Encode PNG Singlethread processname=org.qtproject.example.crio_Android :        375 us, width=2, height=2
D OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
D ViewRootImpl@12633f4[QtActivity]: setView = DecorView@3d0a71d[QtActivity] TM=true MM=false
D ViewRootImpl@12633f4[QtActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
V Surface : sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
D ViewRootImpl@12633f4[QtActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 3761723392} changed=true
I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
D libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : org.qtproject.example.crio_Android
D mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
D OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xe7b37918
D ViewRootImpl@12633f4[QtActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
D ViewRootImpl@12633f4[QtActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
V InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@d6c9b60 nm : org.qtproject.example.crio_Android ic=null
I InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
V InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ad59819 nm : org.qtproject.example.crio_Android ic=null
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.crio_Android/qt-reserved-files/plugins/styles/libqandroidstyle.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
**F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8731 (qtMainLoopThrea)**
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This [Qt Bug Report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57909), while not identical may help. It shows the same "unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81" message.  It also suggests a fix in the list of bug comments.

Comment: try to get the full stracktrace from logcat (run `abd logcat` and search for the stacktrace there). Since the actual trace is reported by a different process, it is not displayed by default